# barplot scale Y axis

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I try to create a barplot for this dataframe :

```
    WeekInMonth NBR_IMPR
0        1      390871847
1        2      742535347
2        3      726636751
3        4      803836568
4        5      369273437
```

I use this basic code :

```
# Barplot
sns.barplot(x ="WeekInMonth" , y ="NBR_IMPR" , data=sub_imp)
```

But the issue is i got numbers for Y axis from 0  to 1.2
Is it any way to change this scale to represet really the true numbers of NBR_IMPR column?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you notice the `1e8` in the top left-hand corner?

Comment: Yes i noticed it